# How to get realistic glass material for ashtray in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, glass

I'm done modeling the ashtray but I'm having trouble getting realistic glass material. This is my render in cycles.
[image]
[image]
I have a picture of my ashtray and would like the effect below.

[image]

[image]
only ashtray object

Comment: A big help in making a realistic render is to correctly place the object in its environment. Try to match the scene by adding a plane below the object and move the light so it matches the reference. However you should note Cycles is notoriously not the best tool to render nice caustics like you see below the reference.

Comment: The file is the one you've used for the screenshot? There are no lights, no material on the ashtray...

Comment: well...first i would improve the mesh and go in edit mode -> recalculate outside

Comment: also give it a bit of noise to the surface, both for bump and roughness

Comment: I have placed a file that contains a ready modeled object. Yes, it is not file from screenshot. I am going to use the ashtray in another scene, where I will throw some objects that I have designed. There I will work on the light and the surroundings. The lower part of the ashtray was difficult and the subdivision surface or bevel modifiers caused visible errors in the mesh and i get crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 noise textures to add a bit of bump to the surface and a bit of roughness to the transparency. Also maybe you should bevel the edges a bit to make them a bit less sharp.

[image]

Comment: You're right. I look much better. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: As Marty says, if you want to show the result, please edit your original question  ;)